# Can you add a 'select all' option to a webform_select_options_list?

Tags: webforms

I have a webform that collects a list of flagged items. I'd like to add a "select all" option, because the list can get fairly long (50+) selections, and it can be tedious to manually check the boxes.

I'm using webform with views, sessions, and custom webform_select_options_info function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Checkall module](https://www.drupal.org/project/checkall) enables this functionality for any `checkboxes` form element.

> This module provides an extension to the builtin checkboxes element
>   that allows developers add "check all" / "toggle" / "uncheck all"
>   actions to them. This is specially useful for checkboxes that have a
>   lot of elements.

A [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) on your webform with this module should get you there.

Comment: so, I'm looking at this now, and it says I need to update the system to 7.8, Is that the drupal core?

Comment: Yes, you need system (core) greater than 7.8. Looking at [the module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/checkall/tree/checkall.info?h=7.x-1.x), it looks like it has the format of its .info incorrect; it should be `dependencies[] = system (>= 7.8)`. The 7.x branch is still in dev so there's likely to be other bugs.